# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture while running bin/gremlin.sh

Tags: titan

im trying to setup Titan db on MAC OS X. unziped titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip...in bin folder tried to execute gremlin.sh and saw the error.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The class `java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture` was introduced in Java 8. So it Looks like you have an older jre running. Change to Java8 and the exception should go away

See the documentation of [this class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: i have installed jdk 8 too...but how can i tell gremlin.sh where to find java 8...     here is my ~/.bash_profile:export JAVA_HOME=/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

export JRE_HOME=/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$GROOVY_HOME


export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: @user2061181 set the JAVA_HOME variable to java 8